# Non-Gregorian Calendar with jQuery FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, localization, fullcalendar, persian-calendar, jalali-calendar

Does anyone know how can one add a non-gregorian calendar support to jquery [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/)? For example Persian Calendar (Jalalai or Shamsi calendar).

I don't know where to start the customization and what exact classes and scripts are affected by such a feature. I have implemented conversion script in js.

I think that there isn't any built-in support. I'm looking for solution so that I myself can implement it myself.

Jalali calendar (Persian):

- 12 month
- 6 first months are 31 days
- 5 next months are 30 days
- The last month is 29 or 30 days based on being leap year.
- The year starts on first day of spring.
- Today date is 23/05/1389 == 16/08/2010

Thank you,

Comment: I have the same problem, can help me? could you change fullcalendar culture to persian? thank you

Comment: I have done this 4 years ago, I don't remember details, but it is not a difficult task

Comment: I have found my old sources, email me for sending arash1363@gmail.com

Comment: thanks alot for answering, I sent email to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a jQuery plugin that provides support for various world calendars:

http://keith-wood.name/calendars.html

Including Persian, Thai, Islamic, Hebrew, etc...

Comment: thanks
i have seen the demo page, it works fine.
i am not expert in javascript therefore i could not understand the usage and also the integration concept very well.
could you please help me more?
thanks in advance

Comment: It's getting a bit off-topic from your question.  What I would suggest is that you take a look at the page at http://keith-wood.name/calendarsBasics.html and then post back another question with specifics, considering they have a lot of examples and rather excellent documentation.

Answer (score 3):

[This fork](https://github.com/ehsandanesh/fullcalendar) is [fullcalendar version 2.1.1](http://fullcalendar.io/) with support of Persian Jalali calendar.

Everything is like fullcalendar mainline but:

For persian jalali calendar to be enabled you have to just use "lang:'persianJalali'" in your fullcalendar object definition. It is added by me and it is not in mainline of fullcalendar development yet. and it has no interfere with any other fullcalendar configuration object.

Becareful of using "lang:fa" because it does not convert fullcalendar to Jalali format, it just translates default fullcalendar to persian language as it does before.
I used "viewRender" and "eventAfterAllRender" fullcalendar object elements for this conversion so PLEASE BE CAREFUL FOR OVERRIDING THEM.
I even used this pwt-datpicker jquery library for my date conversions so it is my fork new dependancy so add it before using this fork.

Answer (score 1):

Hi everybody I added Jalaali calendar to version 2.6.0 and solved previous issues in this update you can find it from here:
https://github.com/ehsandanesh/fullcalendar