# Can fullcalendar support Hijri Calendar?

Tags: fullcalendar, hijri

I have a fullcallender in my application.
Can fullcalendar support Hijri Calendar ? Any options available?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493064/non-gregorian-calendars-with-jquery-fullcalendar