# How we can implement Hijri calendar instead of Gregorian calendar in PrimeFaces component

Tags: primefaces

I am working in PrimeFaces 5.1 and have `<p:calendar/>` component but this shows the Gregorian calendar,now I have a requirement of showing Hijri calendar instead of Gregorian ,how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of links that might help you with that since `<p:calendar>` is a wrapper for jquery datepicker if I am not mistaken.

[PrimeFaces support Islamic/Hijri Calendar?](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=20181)

[non Gregorian calendars with jquery fullcalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493064/non-gregorian-calendars-with-jquery-fullcalendar)