# non-gregorian (jalali) FullCalendar using moment-jalaali plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, jalali-calendar

I need a FullCalendar with Jalaali (Persian) calendar.

There is a nice plugin for moment.js called [moment-jalaali](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/jalaali/). 
As Moment objects are used throughout FullCalendar's API, I think there should be an easy way to convert default calendar to Jalali using that plugin.

I've already found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493064/non-gregorian-calendars-with-jquery-fullcalendar/26425370#26425370) which does not use moment.js and does not sound to be a good solution.

Comment: I think Moment-jalali is simplest way to do this. Maybe I couldn't understand right what you mean!

Answer (score 6):

I added Jalaali calendar to version 2.6.0 and solved previous issues in this update you can find it from here:
https://github.com/ehsandanesh/fullcalendar