# can i add Hijri Date to full calendar with laravel

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel

i have full calendar in my website developed by laravel  can i make fullcalendar support hijri date and  transform to Arabic the dates and months to arabic ??

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this answer [Non-Gregorian Calendar with jQuery FullCalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493064/non-gregorian-calendar-with-jquery-fullcalendar)
 it should give a good starting point.

and i think those packages will be usefull

1. [GeniusTS/laravel-hijri-dates](https://github.com/GeniusTS/laravel-hijri-dates)
2. [alkoumi/laravel-hijri-date](https://github.com/alkoumi/laravel-hijri-date)